# Security Certificate on Webservices

Tags: c#, web-services, ssl, soap

I have a webservice from a partner that am developing against in C#. I have browsed it on SOAPUI and this is the request

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:ser="http://service.bank.pmt.tpa" xmlns:xsd="http://bean.bank.pmt.tpa/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
  <ser:processPaymentNotificationReport>
     <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
     <ser:pmtNotifyReport>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:amountPaid>?</xsd:amountPaid>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:bankBranchCode>?</xsd:bankBranchCode>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:bankTransNo>?</xsd:bankTransNo>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:datePaid>?</xsd:datePaid>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:paymentRegTransNo>?</xsd:paymentRegTransNo>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:status>?</xsd:status>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:taxPayerName>?</xsd:taxPayerName>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:tin>?</xsd:tin>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <xsd:transactionId>?</xsd:transactionId>
     </ser:pmtNotifyReport>
  </ser:processPaymentNotificationReport>
```

when i input the parameters and browse, this is the response

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
  <soapenv:Fault xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <faultcode>wsse:InvalidSecurity</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Missing wsse:Security header in request</faultstring>
     <detail/>
   </soapenv:Fault>
  </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have reconstructed the request xml in my code then send the xml to the partner by invoking their url. Now i find out that i cannot hit their webservice until i implement the security certificate. I have no idea how i can import that security certificate and use it in my code, need some help pease.

Comment: I am constructing this xml request in a windows service project

Comment: What do you mean by 'the security certificate'? Are they asking you to use a certificate for client based authentication? If so, read this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648360.aspx

Comment: No their webservice has security @user469104

Comment: Then you need to provide more information on the problem you are experiencing. If they have a certificate, all you should have to do is to change the URL you are invoking from 'http://' to 'https://'. What are the exceptions / errors you are getting? Include all relevant information in your question, you then stand a much bigger chance of being helped.